# How to insert css arrow into html page and make it clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

Hello guys I'm making a FAQ page for a project in my uni, and I've got everything working, but I wanted to make it look nicer. I made an arrow into a css file, and I wanted to put it into my html. In my html there are headers which have a button that shows and hide the content thanks to jQuery. My question is: how can I put the arrow in each header and make it clickable so I can delete the button and by clicking the header it self will display the content?

Thanks for your help

Here is my CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .body
    {
    padding: 10px 6px;
    height: 0;
    background: #ff4400;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 -4px;
    z-index:999;
    }

    .arrow
    {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff4400;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button").click(function () {
           var div= $("#"+this.value);
      div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
    });  
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <title>FAQ</title>
    <h><font size="7">FAQ</font><font size= "5.5">Most frequently asked questions</font></h>
    <div id="buttonDiv"></div>    

    <!-- setting BUTTON 1-->
    <h1><font size="5">QUESTION 1</font><button id="button1" type="button" class="button" value="Show1">Show/Hide</button></h1>
    <!--------------------QUESTION 1 --------------------------------------------->  

    <div>
      <div id="Show1" style="display:none">
        Answer to the question 1
     </div>   
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function () {
       var div= $("#"+this.name);
  div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <div class="arrow"></div>

    <a class="button" name="Show1" href="#">
        <font size="5">QUESTION 1</font>
    </a>
</h1>

<div id="Show1" style="display:none">
    Answer to the question 1
</div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/788NK/6/

Hope is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for help, but my idea was to have the triangle at the beginning of the line and making QUESTION1 clickable, so it would show up the content

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is and you are showing two different html pages

```
$(".arrow").on("click",function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

using

```
cursor:pointer
```

worked for me here:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nEsTT/)

Using your comments, look here

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2JMNR/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clickable").on("click",function() {
    val = $(this).data("val");  
    var div= $("#"+val);
    div.toggle("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
  });
});
```

and do not use ID but class and value is illegal, use data-val:

```
<h1 class="clickable" data-val="Show1"><div class="body"></div><div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: brilliant, but can you make the header: QUESTION 1, clickable? not the arrow, but the header it self, I probably expressed my self badly. Besides looking on the web I found out that a css has to have html tags anyway, Am I wrong?

Comment: To do that, just add an id to your <h1> like `<h1 id="clickable">` and then in the jquery do `$("#clickable").on("click"...` Just make sure everything you want to be clickable is between the `<h1></h1>`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't work out how to make it work. this is the final thing I had, but I tried many things before, I can't even work out how to fix the arrow, can you help please? http://jsfiddle.net/nEsTT/3/